# Is there a way to install ros on ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: ros-lunar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a way to install ros on ubuntu 17.10? How?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/285746/is-there-a-way-to-install-ros-on-ubuntu-17.10?/) by [aleesq](https://answers.ros.org/users/34194/aleesq/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2018-03-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

"a way"? Yes (building from sources, Docker images, etc).

Supported: not until [ROS Melodic](http://wiki.ros.org/melodic/Installation) is completely released.

Please also see #q282619.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-03-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0